# layered PSD or TIFF creation from webpage (either PHP or JS)

Tags: php, javascript, gd, tiff, psd

Does anybody know which programming library I should use to throw a transparent PNG on top of a JPG and export a layered file for photoshop ? like a TIF or PSD or anything that can be loaded in photoshop.

I know the GD library can be used to output to screen or a non-layered file, but I'm wondering is there any format I can output to with proper intact layers...

Preferably something clientside with JS but I can do PHP serverside if that's my only option. I've done a bit of googling on the subject, hard to format the search really.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168614/how-to-create-a-layered-psd-file-from-command-line ?  IMO, this will have to be a server-side solution - PHP or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need a server side solution using PHP and [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) to create layered tiff files.

Also check out the [examples of layers using ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/)

Then you can use `setImageFormat("tiff")` to save the final file as a layered tiff file.

I hope that helps.

Comment: You can use [this command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13514555/1617295) for ImageMagick.