# Is it possible to write a PSD file from ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, psd

I would like to be able to take a number of separate image files, mostly JPGs and PNGs, and programatically write them into a PSD file in ColdFusion.  The idea is that I can create an online tool that I could use to create wedding albums from my digital wedding photos.  Considering the intended use, it is imperative that image quality and color reproduction remain as close to the original as possible.  My thoughts on this would be to import each file into a separate layer, and then set the positioning of the imported image by pixel coordinates.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168614/how-to-create-a-layered-psd-file-from-command-line), which appears to be the only mention of this sort of thing on SO (that I could find).  However, I'd rather not revert to writing this all out in CFExecute.  It seems needlessly complicated to add another language every future developer will need familiarity with, and CFExecute doesn't provide much in the way of monitoring or debugging if problems occur.  But I'll do this if I need to.

Server is currently running ColdFusion 9 on Windows 2000 Advanced Server.  We will probably be upgraded to ColdFusion 10 on Windows 2008 (or newer) by the time this goes to production, but having the ability to test it in my current environment would be a real plus.

Comment: Yes, use imagemagik, not really that complicated and it's reliable and fast!

Comment: FYI. I have read on a few blogs that ColdFusion 10 does not currently work with Windows Server 2012.  I'm sticking with Windows Server 2008 R2 for now.

Comment: You'd think so with both Photoshop and ColdFusion being Adobe products... not so much

Comment: imagemagick is truely magical compared to cf's (java's) jai library. Once you try it, you'll never use cfimage again!

Comment: A bonus of outsourcing image processing to imagemagick is that image manipulation is memory expensive and large processed images wont interfere with you cached items in java. CF allocated memory wont have to churn as much as the separate imagemagick binary has its own dedicated