# How to create a psd layered file from multiple image in python

Tags: python, image, psd

I need to create a psd file to merge several images into a single layered one.
I saw that the *gimp command line* seems to be the only way to be able to do, but I would like to make this tool-independent.
*Would there be another solution ?*

For info I already looked into *psd-tools*, *psdparse*, *pypsd* that allows extracting layers from a psd to make a separate image with it but not the other way around.

o/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had looked into that issue myself some time ago for a client who was adamant on building an online-photo editor using Django.

For proper results you will likely have to rely on a native compiled library in some form or another. As most Python modules will wrap these libraries, you could stick to 
`import os; os.system("gimp ...")` or `from subprocess import call; call(["gimp", "-i -b '(mygimpscript "test.psd" 2000 2000)'..."])` using the [GIMP command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168614/how-to-create-a-layered-psd-file-from-command-line?rq=1) for instance.

From an Adobe [blogger](http://blogs.adobe.com/jnack/2009/05/some_thoughts_about_the_psd_format.html):

> If you’re a developer, PSD’s complexity makes writing a file format
>   reader/writer more difficult. Of course, PSD was never designed as or
>   intended to be an interchange format.

The *[Readme](https://github.com/kmike/psd-tools)* from the current-work-in-progress [psd-tools](https://github.com/kmike/psd-tools), also suggests that good psd-writers are still hard or even elusive to come by.

---

Despite that introduction,

- [GIMP and Python](http://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html) would be a good combination.
- [Pillow 2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.0.0) has some useful features as well.

For full compatibility with *alpha blending*, and *metadata*, the only option you got is using the proprietary COM32 based psd library from Adobe. [Here](http://techarttiki.blogspot.co.at/2008/08/photoshop-scripting-with-python.html) is an example, and [here](http://peterhanshawart.blogspot.co.at/2012/05/python-and-photoshop-code-snippets.html) another.

The advantage is a decent level of documentation. The disadvantage is that you will likely be platform bound.

Unfortunately the answer still appears to be:

***No, there still is currently no way to write psd files in pure Python in a manner that would satisfy a productive level*.**

Comment: I came more or less to the same conclusion and it's good to have another opinion. cheers o/