# is it possible to have multiple layers like in photoshop on imagemagick

Tags: image-processing, svg, imagemagick

eps file which will be opened on AI. The process is, I'll be using Imagemagick to combine all images(.svg, .tif, .png, .jpg) into one file with format of .eps. I did a test and comeup with a good result, however It is not exactly what I want. When you open a AI and embed some images there, you can actually drag those images independently, as if they were treated as separate objects on the artboard. On my test result, Imagemagick seems created only one image. The images are attached to each other.

Guys help me to do this or enlighten me on my understanding here. Hopefully it is possible.

I'm using this code for imagemagick:

```
montage RSVG:d.svg -geometry +5+10 c.png -geometry +200+10 -tile x1  eps2:output.eps
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168614/how-to-create-a-layered-psd-file-from-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a conversation on the imagemagick [Re: Trouble Creating PSD with Layers](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=19775)

It helps me on using Imagemagick to create a psd with layers. :) Just to share, here is my code:

```
convert                  \
  j.png                  \
  b.svg                  \
  gradiant.png           \
    \(                   \
       -clone 0          \
       -clone 1          \
       -clone 2          \
       -background white \
       -mosaic           \
    \)                   \
  -alpha set             \
  -reverse               \
  -colorspace CMYK       \
  test2-mosaic.psd
```

But the thing is, I need to output it as PDF, I try to output it as .pdf and it's good: I can open it on Adobe Acrobat; however, I can't open it on Adobe Illustrator. I think this is another question I have to post.